# Protect cells until some condition is met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Apps script, I am trying to protect few cells until some condition is met
[image]

Please refer above image, if F2 is Done, then remove protection from A2:E2 or protect from editing.

Please help with the script, I want this script to every row.

```
 function onEdit() 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var cell = source.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var range = ss.getRange('A2:E2');

  if (cell == Done) {

    
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    Logger.log

  } else {

    
    var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      protection.remove();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Comment: There are syntactical and semantical errors in the code. I do not think it qualifies as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The `Range.protect()` method requires authorization, so you cannot run it from an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.